# Animating image in infinite loop using CSS

Tags: css, animation, infinite-loop

I have an image of clouds in a full-width `<div>` element. No matter the device, I want to animate the clouds so that they move left to right in an infinite loop, and when the edge of the image is reached, the image starts again.

How would I accomplish this?

(Here is the image of the clouds; note that the left edge height matches the right edge height)

[image: 1]

Comment: Please check this examples you will understood how to make that
http://codepen.io/kevinjannis/pen/wyFga

Comment: Also this http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/DxJka/

Comment: you could use https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ animate.css use Slideinleft and make sure to add
-vendor-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
@keyframes ani{
 0%{background-position: 0 0;}
 100%{background-position: 100vw 0;}
}
div{
 background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iofJk.png) repeat-x 0 / 100% auto;
 height:500px; /* this value is not important, just not zero */
 animation: ani 10s linear infinite ;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: To stop the judder, it might be simpler to just have the [animation run all day like this example](http://jsbin.com/jocekocuwe/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: @misterManSam  Yes! Your answer can change the height of image, mine can not.

Comment: @misterManSam  But after 100000s, this loop will be break. You can change 100000s to 10s to see the result.

Comment: My point is that 100000s is **one entire day**, so that it will have a slight shudder once a day... that is not something that anyone will notice as no one will hang around on the site for an entire 24 hours :)

Comment: Yes, If the questioner need customize the height of image, Your plan is perfect.